# Ajuda na criação de bot para um jogo Web Browser

Tags: jogos, navegador-de-internet, tampermonkey

**Olá, preciso de ajuda para criar um script que faça com que clique automático em um botão ao entrar em uma determinada página do jogo eu jogo.**

**Explicando melhor: O jogo tem um "PVP", que quando eu clicko para entrar na pagina do "PVP" aparece o nome dos jogadores que estão lá dentro da sala de briga, porém eu preciso ser rápido para atacar eles, tenho que clickar para selecionar o nome do jogador e depois clickar no botão atacar, só que eu baixei o tampermonkey e queria executar nele um script que selecionasse automático o nome dos jogadores e depois em seguida clickasse em atacar..Um bot no caso! Como não tenho experiência para criar esse script gostaria que vocês me ajudassem, então peguei os códigos dos 2 botões.**

**O botão que seleciona o jogador ( Preciso que selecione automático ):**

```
<select tabindex="-1" class="select-large"><option value="-">[Escolha...]</option> <option value="[object Object]"> NOMEDOJOGADOR </option></select>
```

**O botão de atacar ( Preciso que logo após selecionar automático, o script clique em atacar sozinho ):**

```
<button tabindex="-1" class="btn btn-inverse btn-large"> Atacar </button>
```

Comment: kkk você quer ajuda para tentar danificar contra a integridade de um jogo? Acredito que ninguém vai te ajudar aqui, as pessoas aqui tem ética.

Comment: Não é danificar a integridade do jogo mano, é apenas uma forma mais rápida de atacar o oponente, mais da metade das pessoas que jogam esse jogo usam script para atacar mais rápido!